# php how to not display text between tags <> // && ^^ %% $$ ## @@ [] **

Tags: php, mysql, echo, between

I have text in mysql $comments, that contains a few tags:

```
echo $comments; 

//result is this

#John# Have a birthday <2.22.2013> [14-00] party /Club/ *Victoria*?
```

I need a php code to not display all tags and contains text, like this:

```
Have a birthday party ?
```

This code that i use BUT IT HIDDEN JUST TEXT CONTAINS BETWEEN [] AND I WANT TO HIDE TEXT FROM OTHER TAGS TOO <>//##$$**()

```
                function replaceTags($startPoint, $endPoint, $newText, $source) {
                return preg_replace('#('.preg_quote($startPoint).')(.*)('.preg_quote($endPoint).')#si', '$1'.$newText.'$3', $source);
                }

                $source= $comments;
                $startPoint='[';
                $endPoint=']';
                $newText='';
                echo replaceTags($startPoint, $endPoint, $newText, $source);
```

What i must change here?
Regards

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What is your definition of a "tag"?

Comment: The guy may not have any idea how to approach the issue. So can't try anything. I've often been in a situation where I don't know how to approach, what to look at. In areas I'm not familiar with. So to me it looks fine to ask such a question provided he doesn't know how to approach instead of waiting for somebody to craft the re for himself.

Comment: akostadinov, in that case I hope you'd ask for directions what to try instead of "Please give me the code".

Comment: Yes, please i have no programming skills

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: @akostadinov It's not. There are places where that is okay, and this is not one of those places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to remove the unwanted parts:

```
preg_replace('@#[^#]+#|<[^>]+>|\[[^\]]+]|/[^/]+/|*[^*]+*@', '', $foo);
```

They all work similarly by matching your delimiters and text in between, e.g.

```
*[^*]+*
```

can be dissected into

```
*      the starting *
[^*]   any character that is not a *
[^*]+  any run of non-* characters
*      the ending *
```

That pattern repeats for all your delimiter pairs and is put into a single large regex (with the alternation `|`) which basically says »Replace any of these patterns by nothing«.

Comment: Please can u put here a working code? Regards

Comment: This is NOT a free-code generating side. Use the given Regex to create your own solution. If you cannot do that, you maybe better want to post at one of the popular job-portals out there, to find someone that can deliver ReadyToRun-Code.

Comment: -1: You _know_ that this sort of question should not be answered. Is this how you've accrued so much rep?

Comment: Looking at my profile, I have indeed accumulated so much reputation mostly by giving answers, not by asking questions. You're free to sort through all of them and figure out whether I mainly answer throw-away questions; I couldn't tell you right now.

Comment: Random note: I honestly *didn't* know (I tend to not hang around on meta). In fact you were the first to tell me. I tend to ask for clarification or close-vote inappropriate questions happily, but still provide an answer; sometimes as vague as the question, sometimes snarky, sometimes helpful. To me at least this sort of question rarely warrants more than half a minute of time. It's not interesting, it's straightforward to answer and the person asking isn't interested in details anyway and likely won't read them. I sometimes deviate from that, but that's mostly out of boredom.